# Kafka Zookeeper Random Restarts

Tags: apache-kafka, hyperledger-fabric, apache-zookeeper

We are running Hyperledger fabric network with Kafka and zookeeper in production using docker swarm on Azure VM (4 Kafka node, 3 zookeeper nodes) it was running fine but just 2 days back suddenly zookeeper had a restart, after that there's continuous restart on zookeeper having time interval of 6-8 hours.

logs on Kafka node

```
 [2020-07-04 07:48:53,492] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=2, leaderId=1, fetcherId=0] Stopped (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2020-07-04 07:48:53,492] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=2, leaderId=1, fetcherId=0] Shutdown completed (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2020-07-04 07:48:53,499] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 2] Removed fetcher for partitions xxxx-xxxxx-xxx-xxxxx.
```

zookeeper leader logs

```
2020-07-04 07:46:27,070 [myid:3] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:3 cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@653] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x10101beb22c0000 type:create cxid:0x4 zxid:0x2e00000114 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/brokers/ids Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /brokers/ids
2020-07-04 07:48:43,084 [myid:3] - INFO  [SessionTracker:ZooKeeperServer@355] - Expiring session 0x2010551ef290000, timeout of 6000ms exceeded
2020-07-04 07:48:43,085 [myid:3] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:3 cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@487] - Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x2010551ef290000
2020-07-04 07:48:43,091 [myid:3] - INFO  [CommitProcessor:3:NIOServerCnxn@1056] - Closed socket connection for client /100.0.20.80:60672 which had sessionid 0x2010551ef290000
2020-07-04 07:48:55,182 [myid:3] - ERROR [LearnerHandler-/100.0.20.80:58940:LearnerHandler@648] - Unexpected exception causing shutdown while sock still open
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
    at org.apache.jute.BinaryInputArchive.readInt(BinaryInputArchive.java:63)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPacket.deserialize(QuorumPacket.java:85)
    at org.apache.jute.BinaryInputArchive.readRecord(BinaryInputArchive.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.LearnerHandler.run(LearnerHandler.java:559)
2020-07-04 07:48:55,183 [myid:3] - WARN  [LearnerHandler-/100.0.20.80:58940:LearnerHandler@661] - ******* GOODBYE /100.0.20.80:58940 ********
2020-07-04 07:49:57,623 [myid:3] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@222] - Accepted socket connection from /100.0.20.80:37838
2020-07-04 07:49:57,637 [myid:3] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@949] - Client attempting to establish new session at /100.0.20.80:37838
2020-07-04 07:49:57,641 [myid:3] - INFO  [CommitProcessor:3:ZooKeeperServer@694] - Established session 0x300ed4720900000 with negotiated timeout 12000 for client /100.0.20.80:37838
2020-07-04 07:49:57,670 [myid:3] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:3 cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@653] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x300ed4720900000 type:setData cxid:0x1 zxid:0x2e000003b2 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/brokers/topics/xxxxxxxxxxxx/partitions/0/state Error:KeeperErrorCode = BadVersion for /brokers/topics/xxxxxxxxxxxx/partitions/0/state
```

my zoo.cfg

```
clientPort=2181
dataDir=/data
dataLogDir=/datalog
tickTime=6000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=2
autopurge.snapRetainCount=3
autopurge.purgeInterval=1
server.1=xxx.xxx.com:2888:3888
server.2=xxx.xxx.com:2888:3888
server.3=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
```

Comment: A majority of the log messages are INFO and they are ok (just stating that the node already exists).  The actual ERROR message looks like a connectivity issue.   Are your VMs set to shutdown at certain times?

Comment: VM are running 24*7. even I have checked MEMORY and CPU utilisation its not more than 20%, also tried increasing zookeeper tick time but nothing worked. after that I just tried scaling VM to 8GB RAM (previously 4 GB) and enabled accelerated networking on VM. after that I haven't seen the error. but this is very strange behaviour on AZURE. we have been running same configuration INFRA on AWS for more than 1.5 year we never faced such problem.